# Capturar o radio button e salvar o Texto no banco

Tags: android

Galera tô conseguindo capturar o RadioButon selecionado para salvar no banco, preciso capturar o radio button em 3 metodos, esses 2 radiobutons estão em um RadioGrup, o radioButton é o tipo.

```
 private Adicionar setAdicionar(Cursor cursor) {
        Adicionar adicionar = new Adicionar();
        adicionar.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        adicionar.setValor(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("valor")));
        adicionar.setTipo(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("tipo")));
        adicionar.setCategoria(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("categoria")));
        adicionar.setData(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data")));
        adicionar.setDescricao(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("descricao")));
        return adicionar;
    }
}
```

E aqui tbm preciso pegar o selecionado

```
private Adicionar lerDadosDoForm(Adicionar adicionar) {
        adicionar.setValor(txtValor.getText().toString());
        adicionar.setCategoria(edtCategoria.getText().toString());
        adicionar.setData(edtData.getText().toString());
        adicionar.setDescricao(edtDescricao.getText().toString());
        adicionar.setTipo(rdbGasto.getText().toString());


        return adicionar;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Para pegar o texto do radioButton selecionado eu utilizo o seguinte código:

```
RadioButton selecionado;
String situacao;
int idSelecionado = status.getCheckedRadioButtonId(); //pega o id do RadioButton selecionado
selecionado = findViewById(idSelecionado); //Seleciona o RB selecionado pelo id
situacao = String.valueOf(selecionado.getText()); //Pega o texto do RB
```

Comment: oq seria o Selecionado e oq seria o status?

Comment: Desculpa, informações adicionadas na resposta.